# iPhone Automatic Device Provisioning Error

Tags: iphone

In my xcode organizer, I click "refresh" on the "Automatic Device Provisioning" and I keep getting this message:

```
An unexpected error occurred. Please try again.  If the problem persists, please contact Apple Developer Support (http://developer.apple.com/support).
```

I know this is just a generic error message, but I cannot for the life of me figure out if it's my fault, or if apple's server is down. The Certificate and Provisioning Profile I got from iTunes connect imported just fine. I see them in the organizer.

Has anyone seen this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally realized that I am an idiot.

I am still not sure what this error message was about, but I was finally able to get codesign by doing the following:

1) Get a "Distribution" certificate from the Provisioing Portal
2) Get a "Distribution" provisioning profile from the Provisioning Portal

This whole time I was using a "development" certificate + provisioning profile, which failed to codesign my app for device+release.

Answer (score -1):

I am just having this error now as well. Right click in the Organiser on the (new and never used) device and choose "Add Device to Provisioning Portal" gives me the above error. Tried 2 devices already, the same error for both.

I suspect it's an Error on Apple's side?